# Facing issue while reusing mongo connection

Tags: php, mongodb, eloquent

I have '**employees**' collection

I'm creating new mongo connection by using following code

```
$mongoObject = DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('employees');

//fetch employee by employee id
$employee = $mongoObject->where('employee_id', $input['employee_id'])->first();

//Fetch all employees 
$employees = $mongoObject->get();
```

Now my problem is that I got first response properly but when I tried to fetch all employees by using same mongo connection it gives only one record.
As per my understanding it's not flushing conditions after I use ->first() of eloquent.

Is there any way to reuse the same mongo connection by using eloquent methods?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After calling first() the limit is being set to 1 which is why get returns one record.

Following code works:-

```
$mongoObject = DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('employees');

//fetch employee by employee id
$employee = $mongoObject->where('employee_id', $input['employee_id'])->first();

//Fetch all employees 
$employees = $mongoObject->newQuery()->from('employees')->get();
```